# javascript function as a class not returning private variable

Tags: javascript, oop, object, javascript-objects, javascript-namespaces

I have used javascript object as a namespace and defined a function as a property.Inside the function there are two property with reference to `this` parameter.One of the property is a function and other is a variable. Now when i called this function(defined as reference to this), i want to return the value of the second reference property(which is a variable). But inside the scope of this function, I am not able to get the value of the variable. Is something i am missing here?

Definition

```
var myNameSpace = myNameSpace || {};
myNameSpace.myClass = function(){
    this.myVar = someValue;
    var someConstantVar = 17.012;
    this.myFunction = function(){
        ...
        var returnValue = someConstantVar + ((this.myVar+22)*1.09);
        return returnValue; 
    };
}
```

Usage

```
var testObject = new myNameSpace.myClass();
testObject.myVar = someNewValue; 
var output = testObject.myFunction();
```

Now there is an error of undefined `this.myVar`(which is likely). So how do I get the value of `this.myVar` inside the function.

Comment: Now that the question has been updated — what is your expected result here and what is actually happening? Your problem is still not clear.

Comment: i really cant understand what the author of the question is trying to get. @Dmytro answer is correct.

Comment: illustrate a fiddler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var myNameSpace = myNameSpace || {};
myNameSpace.myClass = function() {
    this.myVar = 3;
    this.myFunction = function() {

        return this.myVar;
    };
}

var testObject = new myNameSpace.myClass();
var output = testObject.myFunction(); // 3
```

`myVar` is a field of every object that you create via `new myNameSpace.myClass()`. To access fields from inside the object, you have to use `this`.

Also, in this implementation, `myVar` is actually public, so you can access it directly like this:

```
output.myVar // 3
```

To make `myVar` a private variable, you can do this instead:

```
var myNameSpace = myNameSpace || {};
myNameSpace.myClass = function() {
    var myVar = 3;

    this.myFunction = function() {
        return myVar;
    };
}
```

Comment: actually the problem is not with returning the variable value, I want to manipulate the value of that variable inside the function, something like `this.myFunction = function() { return this.myVar+22; };`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal then clarify what you want exactly in the question.

Comment: I have update my question for your better understanding. have a look.

Comment: Okay I got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
var myNameSpace = myNameSpace || {};
myNameSpace.myClass = function(){
   var that = this;
    this.myVar = 'someValue';

    this.myFunction = function(){
        return that.myVar; //Here I need to return this.myVar
    };
}
```

"this" inside "this.myFunction" is has scope only to "this.myFunction". You need scope of "myClass"